# MySQL select multiple tables where fieldnames are duplicate

Tags: php, sql, pdo

when i select multiple tables in MySQL via PHP PDO statement like this

```
$query = "SELECT * from offers, courts";
```

how do i output duplicate fieldnames for example there are the following fields present in each table

```
offers.description and courts.description
```

when i do a while/foreach to loop trough the keys, im only able to output something like this

```
$row['caption']
```

i would need something like this tough

```
$row['courts.caption'] or $row['courts']['caption']
```

how would i achieve that?

Sadly the tables have got no relationship.

Comment: If tables have got no relationship, there is no point in joining them.

Comment: Did you check what results are coming out from your SQL with such query? 
You have to mixed it with some relation etc.. other way you will get crazy results, the second table will be  assign to each row at from the first one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can select the fields like:

```
$query = "SELECT o.description as OfferDescription, c.description as CourtsDescription from offers o, courts c";
```

and then use : `$row['OfferDescription']` OR `$row['CourtsDescription']`